# Filter the object based on the nested array object

Tags: javascript

Recently, I gave an interview and rejected there were about 10 questions. Each question had `60` seconds. There was a question that went wrong but I was curious why it happened.

I have to filter those objects in which given `SearchValue` match with the `list` array object `name` property. The `search` value was already given.

**For example:**

```
const SearchValue = 'event';
```

It is filtered array because `list[0].name` property value match with the the `event` text.

```
const res = [
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Events',
        list: [
            {
                id: 1,
                name: 'Event Ticketing System',
                slug: '/'
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                name: 'Events Management Software',
                slug: '/'
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

The `name` property contains value something like this `Online Translation Services` and `Spelling and Grammar Check` etc. If the search value match with the `text`  then save it those filtered objects and `console.log`. The data-set was something like this.

```
const listing = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Language',
    list: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Online Translation Services',
        slug: '/'
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Spelling and Grammar Check',
        slug: '/'
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'TEFL Courses',
        slug: '/'
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        name: 'Language Learning',
        slug: '/'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Events',
    list: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Event Ticketing System',
        slug: '/'
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Events Management Software',
        slug: '/'
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

My implementation was this.

```js
const SearchValue = 'event';

const listing = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Language',
    list: [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'Online Translation Services',
        slug: '/'
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Spelling and Grammar Check',
        slug: '/'
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'TEFL Courses',
        slug: '/'
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        name: 'Language Learning',
        slug: '/'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Events',
    list: [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'Event Ticketing System',
        slug: '/'
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Events Management Software',
        slug: '/'
      }
    ]
  }
];

const res = listing.filter(object => {
  if (Array.isArray(object.list) && object.list.length > 0) {
    return object.list.filter((item) => {
      return item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(SearchValue.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
    });
  }
});


console.log('Result Array', res);
```

If anyone can provide a good solution really appreciated. I also want to know What was wrong with this logic?

Comment: I think this might answer your question https://medium.com/better-programming/array-includes-method-in-javascript-38d919b59c41

Comment: Nothing matches with `event`... so you should have an empty array??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) along with [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to verify if any of the elements of the `list` property of each object contains the search text in its `name`.

```js
const listing = [ { id: 1, name: 'Language', list: [ { id: 1, name: 'Online Translation Services', slug: '/' }, { id: 2, name: 'Spelling and Grammar Check', slug: '/' }, { id: 3, name: 'TEFL Courses', slug: '/' }, { id: 4, name: 'Language Learning', slug: '/' } ] }, { id: 2, name: 'Events', list: [ { id: 1, name: 'Event Ticketing System', slug: '/' }, { id: 2, name: 'Events Management Software', slug: '/' } ] } ];
const SearchValue = 'event';
const res = listing.filter(({list})=>
 list.some(({name})=>name.toLowerCase().includes(SearchValue.toLowerCase())));
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Wow ES6 has introduce array methods that I have to know. Clean solution

Comment: so just one of `list` items has `SearchValue`, select all first and second lever data?

Answer (score 0):

Check with RegEx and test

```js
const SearchValue = 'event';

const listing = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Language',
    list: [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'Online Translation Services',
        slug: '/'
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Spelling and Grammar Check',
        slug: '/'
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'TEFL Courses',
        slug: '/'
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        name: 'Language Learning',
        slug: '/'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Events',
    list: [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'Event Ticketing System',
        slug: '/'
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Events Management Software',
        slug: '/'
      }
    ]
  }
];

const res = listing.filter(object => {
  if (Array.isArray(object.list) && object.list.length > 0) {
    // Check items with RegEx test
    // and update object.list
    object.list = object.list.filter(item => new RegExp(SearchValue, 'i').test(item.name));
    // Return true if list length > 0
    if(object.list.length > 0) return true;
  }
});


console.log('Result Array', res);
```

Comment: I've updated my answer, check comments in code below

Answer (score 0):

[Array Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

`let newArray = arr.filter(callback(element[, index, [array]])[, thisArg])`

#### callback

Function is a predicate, to test each element of the array. Return true to keep the element, false otherwise.

#### Return value

A new array with the elements that pass the test. If no elements pass the test, an empty array will be returned.

```js
const SearchValue = 'language';

const listing = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Language',
    list: [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'Online Translation Services',
        slug: '/'
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Spelling and Grammar Check',
        slug: '/'
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'TEFL Courses',
        slug: '/'
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        name: 'Language Learning',
        slug: '/'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Events',
    list: [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'Event Ticketing System',
        slug: '/'
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Events Management Software',
        slug: '/'
      }
    ]
  }
];

const res = listing.reduce((pre, object) => {
  if(!Array.isArray(object.list) || object.list.length <= 0)
    return pre
  
  object.list = object.list.filter((item) =>  item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(SearchValue.toLowerCase()) > -1);
    
  return object.list.length > 0 ? [...pre, object] : pre;

}, []);


console.log('Result Array', res);
```

Comment: I updated my question Why your results are returning  `{ "id": 1,"name": "Language", "list": []}` in the filtered result.